# Python: How to read a text file into a dictionary when each key and value is on a new line?

Tags: python, dictionary, delimiter, key-value

I'm sure there is an example of this somewhere already but I haven't been able to find it.
I have a text file that looks like this:

apple
1
orange
3
pear
6
plum
8

etc...

I want to make a dictionary where the keys are the string of each fruit and the corresponding values to be the line below it. When I tried delimiting with the newline character '\n', it created a dictionary with every line as a key and empty corresponding values. How can I achieve this?

Here is my current code for reference:

```
fruit_dict = {}
with open('fruit.txt') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        (key, val) = line.split('\n')
        fruit_dict[key] = val
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a quick and easy method

```
fruit_dict = {}
with open('fruit.txt') as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        key = line.strip()
        value = file_object.readline().strip()
        fruit_dict[key] = value

print(fruit_dict)
```

Note: this can probably be improved

**How it works:**
It loops through the file and the key is assigned the line but the extra read line makes the seeker go one line down and therefore works with the for statement